# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined react.js redux

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, auth, react-router-dom

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь создать функциональный компонент в React.js - PrivateRoute, для контроля доступа в приложении. Внутри, Route, в случае, если пользователь вошел, рендерит переданный компонент, иначе, делает редирект на '/login'. Видел такой компонент у нескольких людей, все работает. У меня почему то ругается на props. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {userActions} from "src/store/actions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        this.props.session()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    session: () => dispatch(userActions.getProfile())
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: пришлите полное описание ошибки

Comment: то есть всю страницу заскринить?